# Why should I keep the root user if I'm not supposed to use it?

Tags: ubuntu, security, ssh, sftp

I'm on a fresh VPS with Ubuntu Server 12.04. I wanted to ask you the good practices to apply to enhance security over a stock Ubuntu-server.

This is what I did up to now:
[I added Google Authenticator to SSH](http://www.howtogeek.com/121650/how-to-secure-ssh-with-google-authenticators-two-factor-authentication/), then I created a new user (whom I'll use instead of 'root' for SSH & SFTP access) which I added to my /etc/sudoers list below 'root', so now it's:

```
 # User privilege specification
 root     ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
 new_user ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

Then I edited sshd_config and set PermitRootLogin to 'no'. Then restarted the ssh service.

Is this ok? There are a few things I'd like to ask you though:

1) What's the sense of adding a new (sudoer) user whilst the root user still exist (ok it can't access with root privilege but it's still there..)?
2) System files are owned by 'root'.. I want to use my new_user to access via SFTP but with it I can't edit those files!! Should I mass-CHMOD 'em so that new_user has write perms too? What's the good practice on this?

Thanks in advance, I hope you'll tell me if I did something wrong and/or other ways to secure the system. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a good start.

The new_user account would gain elevated privileges with the 'sudo' command. This requires the new_user's password be entered when prompted (and it remembers for a short period of time, so it's not every time you use it) and is thus more secure than a regular root account that always has elevated privileges.

To view a root-owned log file, you would run `sudo less /var/log/foo` and then enter the new_user account's password.

To disable the 'root' account, you can use the `passwd` command.

```
sudo passwd -d root
```

This will delete the password. If you only wish to disable the account and wish to be able reinstate it if necessary, the `-l` and `-u` options will lock and unlock the account, respectively.

Comment: Ok but what should I do with the "default" root user? Isn't more secure to deny him some operations (or even remove him from sudoers)?
Otherwise it's the same if I used 'root' (with PermitRootLogin set to 'no') instead of new_user.. am I wrong?

Comment: Sure. Added that to the answer. The 'passwd' command is actually great for that stuff.

Comment: Last question: are there downsides on disabling root account?
For example I run nginx, php5-fpm, mysql, exim4, etc.. would they be affected? I think no because they use their own users.. anyway.. :)

Comment: There may be depending on your config, but the service users for nginx, mysql, etc. are exactly how you mitigate those issues. Those services should be running under service-specific users. Ubuntu doesn't have an enabled root user by default, and that OS works just fine with only 'sudo' and service-oriented system users.

Answer (score 0):

you may be also interested in changing ssh port, changing authorized IP range in iptables, not using sudo and use a very strong password for root.

Comment: a) Security by Obscurity Isn't. b) IPs can be spoofed. c) Sudo is far better than running root for everything. d) If a local account is compromised, it's easier to limit damage if they can't get to a root user.